# What does >/dev/null 2>&1 mean?

Tags: shell, scripting, null

```
diff file1 file2 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I know what this does. It's running the command diff, and it checks its exit status, ignoring the output of diff.

I just don't know what this part means:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

what's  > 
and &

(Not sure what these are called, so I can't look this up)
(This is in Bourne Shell)

Comment: I can't believe this is not a duplicate... I couldn't find one anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [In the bash shell, what is " 2>&1 "?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21)

Answer (score 4):

`>/dev/null` redirects standard out to `/dev/null`, i.e. throw the output away. `2>&1` redirects standard error to standard out; in this case, it means to throw all the error output away as well. You can google for shell output redirection for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, as only the exit status is wanted, this command can be simplified to that one, which doesn't need to redirect its output to the bit bucket:

```
cmp -s file1 file2
```